# How to Copy twitter account image to server?

Tags: php, twitter

I am using the twitter api to access some account details. It's been made clear that you can easily get the twitter account image:

http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1260994338/P3030586-2_bigger.jpg

However, when i try to copy() this image in PHP to my local server it doesn't work. It seems you can't even ping the address as 'could not find host'.

How can I copy the twitter account image to my local server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$twitsImg ='http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1260994338/P3030586-2_bigger.jpg';

$twit=file_get_contents($twitsImg);
$new_img = basename($twitsImg);

file_put_contents($new_img,$twit);
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is that the php ini-file variable `allow_url_fopen` is turned off, as it should be. You need to be using cURL to get the file. cURL is usually installed on web servers by default. This example works on my site:

```
<?php
function save_image($img,$path){
    $ch = curl_init($img);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    $data=curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    if(file_exists($path)){
        unlink($path);
    }
    $fp = fopen($path,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $data);
    fclose($fp);
}

save_image("http://a0.twimg.com/profile_images/1260994338/P3030586-2_bigger.jpg","up/file2.jpg");
?>
```

Also make sure you have the right CHMOD (775) set on your destination folder.